# Group policy issue: when I'd like to write a compact disk

Tags: group-policy, windows-server-2012

I couldn't write compact disk in any machines in our local domain even if I set the `deny write cd` feature to `Not Configured` or `disable`.

Every PCs have windows 7 and our server is windows server 2012.

For more tests, I added a new system with windows 7 OS to our domain. It has a CD-Writer.

I could write CD. But, if I set the `deny write cd` feature in windows server 2012 group policy to `Enable` and then return that to `Not Configured` or `disable` again, I couldn't write CD.

All GP's feature could apply except `deny write cd`.

I edited the `Registry Key` by following this link:

[CD-R drive or CD-RW drive is not recognized as a recordable device](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316529)

But I couldn't write CD again.

If I log out and log in again the above `Registry Key` was deleted.

Could anybody help me please?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the policy to `disabled`, update (`gpupdate /force`) the computers so that they apply the new setting, and then set the policy back to `not configured`.

`Not configured` generally means no setting is applied for that item anymore - it doesn't clear a previous value, so your previous value denying write to CD is still set in the registry.

Alternately, with the group policy set to `not configured`, you'll be able manually change the registry key that controls this behavior.